# Doesn't lambda K-calculus include lambda I-calculus?

Tags: lambda-calculus, combinatory-logic

[To mock a mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Mock_a_Mockingbird), chapter 18:

> From just S and K you can derive *any* combinatorial bird whatsoever!

Same book, chapter 19

> […] with just the two birds J and I, we would ultimately get the same birds as if we started with B, T, M, and I. The kestrel K would never appear, […], nor would a whole host of birds derivable from S and K.
>
> The theory of combinators derivable from […] J and I -- is technically known as the $\lambda$I-calculus. The theory of combinators derivable from S and K is known as the $\lambda$K-calculus. Neither theory can be said to be "better" than the other; each has applications which the other does not.

So from S and K we can derive any combinatorial bird, whereas from J and I we can derive a lot of birds, but at least not K (nor some birds derivable from S and K). So how is it possible that $\lambda$K-calculus is not better than $\lambda$I-calculus?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "λK-calculus is not better than λI-calculus"? What do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco, what does the author mean by "better"? That's what I mean I guess.

Comment: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16508/are-the-lambda-i-calculus-and-the-lambda-k-calculus-equivalent

Answer (score 0):

The $\lambda K$-calculus is actually better because you have the $K$-combinator, so it's much easier to work with since you can discard variables easily. That said, the $\lambda I$-calculus is still **Turing equivalent**. It can define all computable functions, this is proved in *The Calculi of Lambda Conversion - Alonzo Church* in the chapter *Combinations, Godel Numbers* by a recursive translation from lambda terms to the I,J combinator set.

Comment: I assume _Turing equivalent_ means [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/134286/78492). I don't have that book. Could you give a hint about how the $\lambda I$-calculus can accomplish something that the $\lambda K$-calculus would accomplish only using $K$?

Comment: Persons interested in linear logic might dispute your assertion that “The $\lambda K$-calculus is actually better”.  Such a person might hold that the $\lambda K$-calculus was _worse_ for the reason you gave.